# PHP Баг при записи файла

Tags: php, файлы

```
$fullcont3 = 'content/content1.txt';
$article3 = '';
 if (file_put_contents($fullcont3, $article3) === TRUE) {

    echo "TRUE";
    } else { echo "FALSE"; }
```

// Возвращает FALSE но файл записывается

// Собственно вопрос в том , почему FALSE возвращает?

Думаю потому что , возвращает количество байтов записанных в файл , в данном случае возвратит 0 , а 0 === FALSE

Comment: 0 !== FALSE . Тождественность это проверка на равенство с учетом типа

Comment: ну так 0 вроде как и равен FALSE с учетом типа

Comment: @S1lllver, тип число не может быть равен типу булевского значения.

Comment: да , точно , о чем это я

Comment: не заметил строку "при преобразовании в boolean"
При преобразовании в boolean, следующие значения рассматриваются как FALSE:

само значение boolean FALSE
integer 0 (ноль)

Answer (score 4):

file_put_content Возвращает либо количество байтов (число), либо FALSE.

Он **никогда** не возвращает TRUE.

C учетом проверки на тождественность, первый If никогда не выполняется.

Comment: вернет TRUE , если === заменить на == и
'' заменить на '1'

Comment: метод не возвращает true.
он его приведет к true в таком случае, если использовать сравнение

Comment: это я и хотел сказать , плюс

Answer (score 1):

```
if (file_put_contents($fullcont3, $article3) === FALSE)
    echo "Запись не удалась";
else
    echo "Запись удалась";
```